# Json_decode null. Проблема при работе с json строкой

Tags: json, php

Есть `json` строка `{"name":"sector"}` но при попытке работать с ней через `php`, а именно через функцию `json_decode` нам возвращается значение `NULL`. Читали по этому поводу, пишут что возможно не верный `json`.

Сделали следующее:

```
$strTmp = "{\"name\":\"sector\"}";
$jsonTmp[] = $json;
$jsonTmp[] = $strTmp;

if($json === $strTmp) {
echo "Строки равны";
} else {
echo "Строки не равны<br />";
var_dump($strTmp);
echo "<hr />";
var_dump($json);
echo "<hr />";
}
foreach($jsonTmp as $string)
{
echo '<br />Decoding: ' . $string;
json_decode($string);

switch(json_last_error())
{
case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
echo ' - No errors';
break;
}

echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

В итоге получается такая картина:
Строки не равны

```
string(17) "{"name":"sector"}"
string(37) "{"name":"sector"}"

Decoding: {"name":"sector"} - Syntax error, malformed JSON 
Decoding: {"name":"sector"} - No errors
```

Получается `json` строка "короче" временной строки.
Не могли бы вы подсказать в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @EnigmA2030, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Убедитесь в том, что страницы у вас в кодировке utf-8 **без BOM**

Comment: Это уже проверили сразу

Answer (score 1):

```
string(17) "{"name":"sector"}"
string(37) "{"name":"sector"}"
```

Вас не смущает, что у обоих ответов разная длинна строк (17 и 37)?

Скорее всего, у вас во втором случае есть еще HTML тэги, которые в браузере не видны. Попробуйте просмотреть исходный код страницы, или написать что-то в духе:

```
$jsonTmp[] = strip_tags($json);
```

Comment: Конечно смущает, в этом и было подозрение как так у двух визуально одинаковых строк разная длина. Но в проблеме разобрали, оказывается перед сохранением значение свойства обрабатывалось htmlspecialchars и все " становились &quot; поэтому напрямую со значением свойства работать не получалось. А var_dump в html не показывал что они заменены. Пришлось перед работой с ним делать htmlspecialchars_decode и только тогда эту json строку правильно  воспринимает json_decode.